# Codeigniter Session deletes itself after 5 minutes

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session

I have tried using every hack and every slightly changed Session.php I have done various different config changes and still it deletes itself after 5 minutes, and its always 5 minutes no matter what. I am using the latest codeigniter and using java scripts for amazon banners.
I am testing in Localhost.
All the session needs to do is check if the user is logged into facebook and store the session just like my other apps that work great due to no javascript.

Comment: Which session driver are you using? Cookie or database? Post your session config from application/config/config.php

Comment: Cookie

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'gazsession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'gazsessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 6000;

Comment: I guess since I have had no luck getting the sessions to work I would be better of writing a php session instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am full of cold so the last couple of days have seemed like the end of the world haha but it seems to be fixed this morning fingers crossed.
Changes in config
$config['sess_table_name']= '';
and also I rewrote model to only get  $this->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data); and rewrote controller to just access this data so now excludes $is_logged_in which has been added to fb_data. 
It has a slightly altered $Session.php but I forget which one and a MY_Session fixed by sirderno 2013.
It has passed the 5 minute mark about ten times this morning without destroying data so fingers crossed one of things above has fixed it. Thanks to everyone who has commented and tried to assist me I appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

That will print out a page with information about your installation.

Check the session section to see what the expire time is set to. I bet it is set to 5 minutes.

Comment: What are you loading into the cookies? Look at what is in that cookie. It is your session data. BTW: You don't need to set sess_table_name if sess_use_database = FALSE.

Comment: fb-data and is_logged_in that's all

Comment: What is session.cookie_lifetime set to?

Comment: Actually,CodeIgniter doesn't use PHP's native sessions at all, so looking at the session info in phpinfo() won't help. It uses either cookies or a database table (cookies are the default).

Answer (score 0):

You have sess_expire_on_close set to TRUE. This means your session expires when the browser window is closed, and seems like the most likely candidate for the root cause of this problem.

If you set it to FALSE, then the user will remain logged in until the session is destroyed, unless you change the expiration time.